# xcode - command line build - required content for platform watchOS is missing IBBuildSupport

Tags: ios, xcode, go-cd, xcode-command-line-tools

I am trying to build my project (iPad app) from go agent. While building from command line, I am getting below error.

Error log: 
Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IBBuildSupport.AssetCatalog.AssetTagScanner.TypeExtension
go-agent: error: Initialization failed.
   Reason: Required content for platform watchOS is missing

I am not using/referring to any of watchOS related libraries. Any one faced similar kind of error?

Comment: I'm also seeing the same issue. I'm running both the GoCD agent and the server locally, and if I run the same build command from the terminal prompt in the Go Agents build directory it works correctly.

Comment: So I'm guessing that there's something amiss or missing in the environment in the Go Agent. I've tried diffing the environment variables between the agent and the CLI, and have found a few differences, but none that make a difference when added to the settings of the GoCD task

Comment: Also, I'm seeing `Could not read the "SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS" build setting, assuming that the project supports iOS only.` earlier in the output from the build command, wonder if that is the underlying cause here - it's looking for WatchKit extensions because it can't read the file that would tell it not to

Comment: are you seeing the same or similar?

Comment: Hey Rich. Thanks for response and suggestions.  I am getting watchOS error while building. I am not seeing this Supported platform error.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem in GoCD to do with an environment variable that is being set by the GoCD agent.

A [Github issue](https://github.com/gocd/gocd/issues/5857) has been opened to fix this.

Meantime, if you have a look at the chat there you'll see that the original reporter has found a workaround, which is to call `unset CFProcessPath` before invoking the `xcodebuild` command.

In my case, I changed the custom command I was using to:

`unset CFProcessPath; bundle exec fastlane build_for_test`

and the build is passing

(I tried using a separate command for the `unset CFProcessPath`, but the environment variables appear to revert between them - so I was forced to combine the two).

Comment: yeah this workaround works for me. Able to build successfully. Thanks!